# Cannot start Android Emulator: "Unable to load VM from snapshot"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I tried to launch the android emulator from Eclipse but the emulator will not start.

When I try to start it I get the following error:

> emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has
>   been saved for a different hardware configuration.

Any advice?

Comment: thanks for your reply but i found solution....

Comment: Glad you found the solution. For your next question try to spend a little more time writing it. I know it's hard, but it will help you get better answers, sooner. Use the style of the question after Tim's edits above as a guide.

Comment: Edit the AVD to disable the Snapshot

Comment: I voted to your question, but it would be nice if you share the solution with others.

Comment: -1 for not sharing your solution.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe try to disable the hardware snapshot in the Android Virtual Device Manager? It should be installed wherever you installed the android SDK.

[image]

Comment: This is not a *solution* anyway, so it should be presented as a *workaround*. The problem is that error occurs EVEN when it is not true that hardware has changed, so if you actually WANT to use the Snapshot feature so emulator starts a lot of faster, you cannot due this problem. It seems like a bug anyway. I experience it randomly but most of the time I try to start an emulator instance WITHOUT changing nothing and having closing it the right way.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this exact problem. The way I resolved it was to edit the AVD and disable the snapshot from the Android Virtual Device Manager like above and also delete the snapshot files **snapshots.img** and **snapshots.img.default-boot.ini** (disabling snapshot won't delete them automatically). Then edit the AVD and re-enable the snapshot.

This won't entirely resolve the problem at least in my case. I re-enabled snapshot and kept getting the error and tried the above steps several times. The cause for me was that after I launched the AVD I was closing the Virtual Device Manager window. Leaving the manager window open until after I've closed the AVD window solved it for me!

Comment: Hi, same problem. When you launch a new configuration there is not snapshot. On the launch screen uncheck 'launch from snapshot' but leave 'save to snapshot checked.'

Answer (score 1):

I need to recreate Virtual Device. Without that it was creating one or other problem.